# Hi. I created Quasar App - Website. Trying to push it to Heroku and it says Push fail. Providing console with error

Tags: heroku, npm, web-deployment, yarnpkg

I'm trying to push my git to Heroku but it gives an error right at the end. I had a look on console of deploying a project as I understand warnings are not a big deal for crashing the whole app. As I went through console I notice that critical error is

```
quasar: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

As far as I think is something wrong with npm or yarn package but don't really know what exactly. I specified in json file same version of node what I have and same version of npm what I have on my computer. I don't use yarn, could that be an issue ?

Here is my json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Quasar Framework app",
  "productName": "Eldar Tailov",
  "author": "'Eldar' <'tailov47@gmail.com'>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "quasar build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn && yarn build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.14.1",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "~12.18.2",
    "npm": "~6.14.5",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}
```

and here is a log of heroku

```
-----> Node.js app detected

       

-----> Creating runtime environment

       

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       NODE_VERBOSE=false

       

-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  ~12.18.2

       engines.npm (package.json):   ~6.14.5

       engines.yarn (package.json):  >= 1.21.1

       

       Resolving node version ~12.18.2...

       Downloading and installing node 12.18.4...

       Bootstrapping npm ~6.14.5 (replacing 6.14.6)...

       npm ~6.14.5 installed

       Resolving yarn version >= 1.21.1...

       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.5)

       Installed yarn 1.22.5

       

-----> Installing dependencies

       Installing node modules

       

       > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/core-js

       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

       

       

       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents

       > node install.js

       

       

       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported

       

       > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/ejs

       > node ./postinstall.js

       

       

       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents

       > node install.js

       

       

       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported

       

       > node-sass@4.14.1 install /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/node-sass

       > node scripts/install.js

       

       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node

       Download complete

       Binary saved to /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node

       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.XZGoT/_cacache/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node

       

       > node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/node-sass

       > node scripts/build.js

       

       Binary found at /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node

       Testing binary

       Binary is fine

       

       > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js

       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

       

       added 1590 packages in 23.801s

       

-----> Build

       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts

       Running heroku-postbuild

       

       > portfolio@0.0.1 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_bc8b4d0e_

       > yarn && yarn build

       

       yarn install v1.22.5

       info No lockfile found.

warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.

       [1/5] Validating package.json...

       [2/5] Resolving packages...

warning vue2-google-maps > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

warning @quasar/app > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

warning @quasar/app > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

warning @quasar/app > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

warning @quasar/app > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

warning @quasar/app > stylus > css-parse > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > braces > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

warning @quasar/app > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > braces > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

warning eslint-loader@3.0.4: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained

warning workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained

       [3/5] Fetching packages...

       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.

       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.

       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

       [4/5] Linking dependencies...

warning " > eslint-loader@3.0.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".

warning " > workbox-webpack-plugin@5.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".

       [5/5] Building fresh packages...

       success Saved lockfile.

       Done in 45.19s.

       yarn run v1.22.5

       $ quasar build

/bin/sh: 1: quasar: not found

error Command failed with exit code 127.

       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! portfolio@0.0.1 heroku-postbuild: `yarn && yarn build`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.0.1 heroku-postbuild script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.XZGoT/_logs/2020-09-28T01_01_55_709Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed

       

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:

       https://help.heroku.com/

       

       Love,

       Heroku

       

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced exactly the same issue as you did. I was able to fix it from the suggestions in this link. I think it's because the `@quasar/app` was listed in the dev dependencies.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps

Basically, I updated the engine part of `package.json` to match my local env

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">= 12.18.3",
  "npm": ">= 6.14.11",
  "yarn": ">= 1.22.5"
}
```

and then set the YARN_PRODUCTION env variable on heroku to false
`heroku config:set YARN_PRODUCTION=false`

I hope you'll find this useful (P.S. Of course don't set a static value in the engine part, use wildcard instead)

Answer (score 1):

Quasar is probably not installed globally on heroku,

try to run it using npx:

```
"scripts": {
 ...
 "build": "npx quasar build -m ssr",
 "start": "cd dist/ssr; npm i; npm start"
}
```

Comment: You're right about Quasar not being installed globally. 

What worked for me was... first, your method of using npx to install it and since I'm using express as my server I also had to use `"start": "node server.js"`